# Scroll event is firing a function too many time

Tags: flutter, scroll, repeat

I have a scroll listener for hiding and showing the bottom navigation bar, It works perfectly but I discover it will fire the function almost 50 times and more when it meets the condition if I scroll too fast. Which means it will rebuild the widget so many times right? How can I prevent this from happening.

`updateBottomBar` is a callback function to setstate the parent widget.

`bottomBarVisible` is the variable to show and hide the bottom nav bar.

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    scrollController.addListener(() {
      //listener
     
      if (scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
              ScrollDirection.reverse &&
          widget.bottomBarVisible == true) {
        print("it is hide");
        widget.updateBottomBar(false);
      } else if (scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
              ScrollDirection.forward &&
          widget.bottomBarVisible == false) {
        print("it is show");
        widget.updateBottomBar(true);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are already checking `widget.bottomBarVisible == true` before setting it to `false` by calling `widget.updateBottomBar(false)`. So that means, it would only call your function once, right?

If that's not the case, maybe you are not updating the `bottomBarVisible` variable quickly enough. I suggest you update the variable as the first thing to do in your `updateBottomBar()` function, to prevent rapid firing.

Answer (score 0):

`addListener` work multiple time while scrolling is not finished. You can handle using `atEdge` function that will return `true` when scrolling finished.

`sController.position.atEdge`

```
sController.addListener(() async {
          if (sController.position.userScrollDirection ==
              ScrollDirection.reverse && sController.position.atEdge) {
            goNextPage();
          } else if (sController.position.userScrollDirection ==
              ScrollDirection.forward && sController.position.atEdge) {
            goPreviousPage();
          }
        });
```